# How can I set the selected date in ngx-bootstrap/datepicker which is launched when an icon is clicked into a common html input?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a common HTML `date` `input`, and next to it I have a `font-awesome` icon. This icon has the functionality of launching the `bsDatePicker`, however, the selected date is not stored anywhere. I'd like to know how could I make that the selected date is transferred to the date input?

This is the HTML code:

```
//this is the common html input
<input type="date" class="form-control">

//and this is the fa icon that launches the calendar
<em #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker class="fa fa-search"></em>
```

How can I store the selected date in a variable in my component, and then somehow make the input updates its value with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[(bsValue)]="date"` to bind the value of the bootstrap datepicker to a variable and `[value]="date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"` to bind the value of the date input to the same variable:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" [value]="date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'">
<em #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker class="fa fa-search" [(bsValue)]="date"></em>
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-uqz2hr

Note that `input` uses a one-way binding, so updating the date in the input will not change the value of the variable (you can only change it with the datepicker). If you want the changes in the input to be saved as well, you need to add something like this:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" [value]="date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'" 
       (input)="parseDate($event.target.value)">
```

and in ts:

```
public parseDate(e) {
  this.date = new Date(e);
}
```

Comment: I am using ngx-bootstrap date picker and trying to bind [(bsValue)]="date" dynamically but it is not working. when i provide static value then it is working. can you please help ?

Comment: @GobindGupta sure! If you create a new question and post whatever you have so far, I'll try to help

Comment: Thanks for acknowledge, i will surely create my question but i have realised that i need some different functionality. I want to highlight dates using "dateCustomClasses". This is working if i provide dates in constructor while initializing but it is  not working when i set this property dynamically.                                                                                                                               Here is my question link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382244/highlight-selected-dates-by-setting-datecustomclasses-property-dynamically-in

Comment: Thanks but i want the placeholder to be any label (e.g. start date) and when user open calendar then today date should show in selected is it is possible ?