# Highlight selected dates by setting "dateCustomClasses" property dynamically in ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular

I want to highlight dates using "dateCustomClasses" property of ngx-bootstrap datepicker in angular 8. This is working if i provide dates in constructor while initializing but it is  not working when i set this property dynamically.

**Here is my code:**

**schedule.component.html**

```
 <bs-datepicker-inline
                bsDatepicker
                [bsConfig]="proofDatepickerConfig"
                name="interviewDate"
                (bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)">
 </bs-datepicker-inline>
```

**schedule.component.ts**

```
 proofDatepickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

      getInterviewScheduling() {
    
            this._candidateService.getinterviewScheduling().subscribe((res: any) => {
                
         this.proofDatepickerConfig = Object.assign( {},
                        {
                            containerClass: 'theme-default',
                            showWeekNumbers: false,
                            minDate: new Date(),
                            dateCustomClasses: [{ date: new Date(res.result.availabilityDates), classes: ['bg-warning'] }],
                        }
                    );
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the date property as today date and check it. If that works, then the problem is your response object **res.result.availabilityDates** and also validate the proper value is passed to the Date object.

```
import { DatepickerDateCustomClasses } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
dateCustomClasses: DatepickerDateCustomClasses[];

this.dateCustomClasses = [
      { date: new Date();, classes: ['bg-danger', 'text-warning'] }
];
```

Please check this link for your references (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dafgtl?embed=1&file=app/ngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts)

Comment: I have checked date property with today date and it is not working. It works only in constructor @Muthupriya

Comment: That's really bad. Could you share me the scenario when did you try to change those values dynamically? @GobindGupta

Comment: If you check schedule.component.ts code above, i tried to change values dynamically in the getInterviewScheduling() function. @Muthupriya

Comment: When that function is going to invoke? @GobindGupta

Comment: ngOnInit() function. @Muthupriya

Comment: I tried your code. I can get the date custom class on ngOnInit(). Did you import bootstrap css file(<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">) in your index.html? @GobindGupta

Comment: yes i have imported bootstrap css file. @Muthupriya

Comment: I think your API service call takes some time to render that's why it won't apply the custom class.